# Redefinition issue in frameworks when integrate in crossplatforms like kony

Tags: objective-c, temenos-quantum, fscalendar

I am new to ObjC and I am using FSCalendar framework for multiple date selection. When I run this project in iOS , everything works fine but when I do this as an FFI for kony , I am getting too many errors like the following. Can anyone help me to resolve these bugs?

[image]

```
#import "FSCalendarConstants.h"

@class FSCalendar;

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, FSCalendarCellState) {
    FSCalendarCellStateNormal      = 0,
    FSCalendarCellStateSelected    = 1,
    FSCalendarCellStatePlaceholder = 1 << 1,
    FSCalendarCellStateDisabled    = 1 << 2,
    FSCalendarCellStateToday       = 1 << 3,
    FSCalendarCellStateWeekend     = 1 << 4,
    FSCalendarCellStateTodaySelected = FSCalendarCellStateToday|FSCalendarCellStateSelected
};

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, FSCalendarSeparators) {
    FSCalendarSeparatorNone          = 0,
    FSCalendarSeparatorInterRows     = 1
};
```

Comment: See the limitations here and make sure that this is something which is supported.  [http://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/visualizer_user_guide/Default.htm#Foreign_Function_Interface_JS.htm?Highlight=ffi]  It's far more difficult to achieve this in Kony even if it is possible.

Comment: Will check it.. Thanks for your help @highhope